# Bootstrap : form with 4 controls in single row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap in a asp.net web application. I want to have 4 controls in each row. 
Example: Label textbox  label dropdown
I tried the below code, but the controls are not aligned and are not proper. How to make 4 controls in a single row with bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3">
<label> very long text
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<input> textbox
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<label> label info
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<select> label info
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just close the tags and everything is inline

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <label> very long text </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <label> label info </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select> label info </select>
  </div>
</div>
```